# Swagger 2 - modelling arrays to ensure empty collections rather than null fields

Tags: swagger-2.0

We've done quite a bit of swagger modelling, but one thing I am struggling with is how we could define that all our arrays will never be null, but will be an empty collection if we have no data.

Is there a way of explicitly defining this in Swagger?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To define a [model](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-spec/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#schema-object) with a mandatory array, you can use `required` property :

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "required": [
    "nonNullableArray"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "nonNullableArray": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "string"
      }
    },
    "nullableArray": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "string"
      }
    }
  }
}
```